# Synonymize [kinos-journey] to [kino-no-tabi] or vice versa

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Just what the title says. There's one question tagged [kinos-journey](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinos-journey) and three tagged [kino-no-tabi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kino-no-tabi) at the moment, and one of these tags should be a synonym of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [kino-no-tabi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kino-no-tabi) tag has been merged with [kinos-journey](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinos-journey) as the parent tag.